# Why does this regex not work for matching C integer declarations?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm using the following regular expression to match C integer declarations without initialization. The integer might be unsigned:

```
^(unsigned[[:space:]]+|^$)int[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+;$
```

The first part matches `unsigned` followed by a number of spaces, or nothing. The second part matches `int` followed by spaces, plus a variable name and a semicolon.

Unfortunately, this seems to not match any integer declaration that doesn't have `unsigned` in it. What am I doing wrong? Does `^$` in a `(...|...)` pattern do what I expect (match the empty string)? Google and my regex manual isn't helping.

Comment: `^$` matches an entire empty line, since `$` matches the end of the line. If you want to make `unsigned` optional, put `?` after that group.

Comment: However, if I use `(unsigned)?` it apparently matches `garbage` too...

Comment: Not if you anchor it at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Why is so? I didn't remember any semantic differences of ? when anchored...

Comment: If you don't anchor it, you match the declaration anywhere in the line. So it doesn't care if there's garbage before it.

Comment: So `(unsigned)?` does mean "unsigned or nothing", not "unsigned or any garbage"? Hmm thinking of it if it means the latter, it would be pretty useless...

Comment: Note that you could have an `int unsigned` (though it is aconventional to write it in that order). As a compiler writer, you have to handle ghastly stuff that no-one in their right mind would write, but some of the programmers who use compilers aren't in their right minds (I expect you can think of some examples).  Also, you aren't compelled to have a single identifier (you could have multiple identifiers separated by commas), and you are restricted to simple identifiers in general (you can have declarators for pointers, arrays, functions, etc). And identifiers cannot start with a digit.

Comment: `(unsigned)?` means `unsigned or nothing`. The point is that if you don't anchor your regexp, the whole regexp allows garbage before or after it, because it's just looking for a match anywhere in the line. What this means is that an optional element at the beginning or end of the regexp is mostly useless if you don't anchor it (it's not totally useless, because it will fill in a capture group if it' matched).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^[[:space:]]*(unsigned[[:space:]]+)?int[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+;[[:space:]]*$
```

To make a group optional, put `?` after it. `^$` doesn't match an empty string in the middle of a match, it matches an entirely empty string -- `^` matches the beginning of the string, and `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: Are `^` and `$` necessary? I think it is going to return less match than there actually are, due to indentation.

Comment: I've added optional whitespace before and after the declaration.

Comment: In a normal C compiler, you are dealing with a token stream, not lines.  You can have multiple declarations on a single line; you can have a single declaration spread over many lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right. This exercise does not duplicate all the parsing that a real compiler does, it's very simple and only recognizes a tiny subset of declarations.